# What to do with .rawproto files in Android Studio build directory?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

Since upgrading to the latest version of gradle, the build directory is full of files like 'build/android-profile/profile-2017-03-08-15-06-35-881.rawproto'

Currently these are all untracked by git, to avoid having them clutter up the place, is it a good practice to commit them, or add them to .gitignore?

Comment: The entire `build/` directory should be in .gitignore.

Comment: How to remove these files from being generated? I don't want to see my storage usage increasing by no reason. I know I can delete it but this is a little bit annoying.

Comment: You can always run the `gradle clean` task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build folder can be fully ignore by git as 1615903 said.
If you're interest in what the *.rawproto is you can take a look at it here.

[How to prevent rawproto file generation or delete them automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521979/how-to-prevent-rawproto-file-generation-or-delete-them-automatically/48087543#48087543)