# How to prevent rawproto file generation or delete them automatically?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android gradle plugin generates tons of `.rawproto` files in `build/android-profile` directory. What are they used for? Is there a way to disable this madness or automatically delete them?

Comment: As for what are they used for, some one put an answer together over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881718/what-is-the-purpose-of-rawproto-files that might start to explain.

Comment: @JeffRichards you might be interested in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been bugged by it for a long time, and now that I noticed there's gigabytes of this hogging my smallish SSD, I've decided to figure out a way to disable it. For me the most annoying thing before occupying too much space was `gradlew clean` leaving a `build` folder behind.

**Only tested with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`, so YMMV.**

## TL;DR

For **global** application read last section, per-project use this in `rootProject`'s `build.gradle`:

```groovy
com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfilerInitializer.recordingBuildListener =
        new com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.RecordingBuildListener(
            com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriter.get());
// and then `gradlew --stop && gradlew clean` to verify no build folder is left behind
```

## Investigation

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910084/253468 linked by [@JeffRichards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190834/jeff-richards) mentioning `ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java`, I've put a breakpoint there and checked who's calling it by running `gradlew -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --info` (not to be confused with `--debug`) and attaching a remote debugger.

I followed the trail and found that `ProcessProfileWriter.finishAndMaybeWrite` creates the folder and writes. Backtracing on method calls I found that `ProfilerInitializer.recordingBuildListener` controls whether it's called ... and that is initialized directly by `BasePlugin` (`apply plugin: 'com.android.*'`).

So in order to prevent anything from happening I opted to try to disable the guard, by pre-initialized that static field. Thankfully Groovy (and hence Gradle) doesn't give a * about JVM visibility modifiers, so without reflection here's the magic line:

```groovy
com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfilerInitializer.recordingBuildListener =
    new com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.RecordingBuildListener(
        com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriter.get());
```

I know, it's a bit verbose, but it works, and if you import stuff it looks better:

```groovy
ProfilerInitializer.recordingBuildListener = new RecordingBuildListener(ProcessProfileWriter.get());
```

## Applying the magic

In a single-project build (one `build.gradle`) you **must** apply this **before**

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

In multi-project builds (most template projects: `app` folder, `settings.gradle`, and many `build.gradle`s) I suggest you apply it around the `buildscript` block:

```groovy
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
// magic line here
```

Make sure it's before any `apply plugin:`s, and not inside a `buildscript` block.

## Applying the magic globally

Obviously if it bothers us in one project, it will in all cases, so following [Gradle's manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script), create a file in `~/.gradle/init.gradle` or `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\init.gradle` (mind you [this folder can be relocated with `GRADLE_USER_HOME`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)) with the following contents:

```groovy
// NB: any changes to this script require a new daemon (`gradlew --stop` or `gradlew --no-daemon <tasks>`)
rootProject { rootProject -> // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087543/253468
    // listen for lifecycle events on the project's plugins
    rootProject.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        // check if any Android plugin is being applied (not necessarily just 'com.android.application')
        // this plugin is actually exactly for this purpose: to get notified
        if (plugin.class.name == 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin') {
            logger.info 'Turning off `build/android-profile/profile-*.(rawproto|json)` generation.'
            // execute the hack in the context of the buildscript, not in this initscript
            new GroovyShell(plugin.class.classLoader).evaluate("""
                com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfilerInitializer.recordingBuildListener =
                    new com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.RecordingBuildListener(
                        com.android.builder.profile.ProcessProfileWriter.get());
            """)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The global solution did not work for me, but the TL;DR part did, thank you very much!

Comment: @artkoenig what was wrong with the global solution? Are you on 3.0.1, and you made sure to restart the daemon (see first line in `init.gradle`).