# what is the purpose of "rawproto" files?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

In Android Studio, in

`~/StudioProjects/$APPLICATION/build/android-profile/`,

there are many files `profile-*.rawproto`, e.g., `profile-2017-04-25-18-19-51-815.rawproto`.

I have never seen the file suffix `.rawproto`, does this suggest a certain kind of file, and if so, what is this file generally used for?

With some digging online, it seems to be related to Gradle in IntelliJ/Studio, which is a sensible conclusion since it is in the build directory. But this is all the information I am able to find on what this is or what it should do.

Comment: If you want to disable it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087543/253468

Answer (score 5):

That filename pattern is mentioned in [ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/profile/src/main/java/com/android/builder/profile/ProcessProfileWriterFactory.java), part of the Android Gradle plugin. Once a real filename is created, it is passed to [ProcessProfileWriter.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/profile/src/main/java/com/android/builder/profile/ProcessProfileWriter.java) which seems to write some analytics data about the build process to a file. The rawproto file format is probably [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: Is this rawproto file is important for app or i can delete these files manually to reduce the size of the project?